# table with \textwidth is wider than \tcblisting minipage

Tags: tables, tcolorbox

When using a `tabular` with textwidth (manually calculated) it turns out to be wider than the minipage created by `\tcblisting`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength\mylenA
\newlength\invoicedescwidth

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tcblisting}{title=tabular with manual column widths}
\settowidth\mylenA{%   
    \textsf{\textbf{Pos.Total sum}}}
\setlength\invoicedescwidth{%
    \dimexpr\textwidth-\mylenA\relax}       
\begin{tabular}
    {
    r
    p{\invoicedescwidth}
    r
    }%
    \textbf{Pos.} & \textbf{Other text} & \textbf{Total sum} \\
    \hline\\
\end{tabular}
    \end{tcblisting}


    \begin{tcblisting}{title=tabularx with textwidth}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}
    {
    r
    X
    r
    }%
    \textbf{Pos.} & \textbf{Other text} & \textbf{Total sum} \\
    \hline\\
\end{tabularx}
    \end{tcblisting}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: tcblisting with tabular]

Tabularx work. Should both not be the same?
I do not want to use tabularx since the multiple calls during the LaTeX build break calculations that are done in tabularx...

Comment: You would get the same problem also without a tcolorbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting to subtract the `\tabcolsep` spaces and there are six of them. Also, since you're typesetting the table in serif type, using `\textsf` will choose the wrong width.

I'd use `\linewidth` in both instances, but it seems that `\textwidth` is correctly updated in the `tcolorbox`, so if you're typesetting in single column there's no real problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength\mylenA
\newlength\invoicedescwidth

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{title=tabular with manual column widths}
  \settowidth\mylenA{\textbf{Pos.Total sum}}
  \setlength\invoicedescwidth{%
    \dimexpr\linewidth-\mylenA-6\tabcolsep\relax
  }
  \begin{tabular}{
    r
    p{\invoicedescwidth}
    r
  }
  \textbf{Pos.} & \textbf{Other text} & \textbf{Total sum} \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{tcblisting}


\begin{tcblisting}{title=tabularx with textwidth}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
    r
    X
    r
  }
  \textbf{Pos.} & \textbf{Other text} & \textbf{Total sum} \\
  \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{tcblisting}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I actually had the `-\tabcolsep` included but had made a different mistake before that I fixed and forgot to check again with `-\tabcolsep`... But are there 6 and not 2? Even if they are counted double (for both both columns on either side of the gap) should there not only be 4?

Comment: Would there also be a possibility to have this calculation independent of the font? This would not work if I now switch to serif font, right?

Comment: @mrCarnivore How is LaTeX supposed to read your mind in deciding what font *you* want to use in the headers for the *next* table?

Comment: Of course I do not want LaTeX to read my mind. However, there might be a setting to find out what the current font type is that will be used for the next table (assuming no more changes after the check)...

Comment: @mrCarnivore `\settowidth` uses the current font. Additional font selections can be done in the argument. But then you need to use them also when typesetting the headers.